# how to shift non nan value in multiple columns row wise by group? (2nd)

Tags: python, pandas, shift

i have post a similar question which was solved by jezrael perfertly.
but this time i have the same dataframe with a new row called label as bellow:

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | 3 | 7 | nan | 8 | A |
| nan | 5 | nan | 11 | 9 | nan | A |
| 54 | 6 | 84 | 12 | 3 | nan | A |
| 10 | nan | nan | 16 | nan | 45 | B |
| 12 | 93 | 13 | 31 | 5 | 91 | B |
| 73 | nan | 45 | nan | nan | 9 | B |

i want to shift non-nan value n rows according to the label column.

desire output for n = 1

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5 | A6 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | A |
| nan | nan | nan | 7 | nan | nan | A |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 11 | 9 | nan | A |
| nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | B |
| 10 | nan | nan | 16 | nan | 45 | B |
| 12 | nan | 13 | nan | nan | 91 | B |

the solution in previous post without label column is

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().shift(1))
```

so i tried

```
columns = df.drop(columns = ['label']).columns
df[columns] = df.groupby(['label'])[columns].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().shift(1))
```

which it only leave rows with no nan value in all columns
and i can only try using the loop solution

```
for column in columns:
        df[column] = df.groupby(['label'])[column].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().shift(1)).droplevel(level=0, axis=0)
```

and again which is slow when number of columns grow large. Wonder if there is anyway to make my attempted solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `transform` instead of `apply`

```
df.groupby('label')[columns].transform(lambda s: s.dropna().shift(1))
```

Result

```
     A1   A2    A3    A4   A5    A6
0   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
1   NaN  NaN   NaN   7.0  NaN   NaN
2   1.0  5.0   3.0  11.0  9.0   NaN
3   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
4  10.0  NaN   NaN  16.0  NaN  45.0
5  12.0  NaN  13.0   NaN  NaN  91.0
```

Some notes:

- Transform will operate on each column separately as opposed to all columns when using groupby `apply`
- Transform will also broadcast the values back to the original shape after dropping the NaN's

Comment: i got an error message : length mismatch : expected axis has 108167 elements, new values have 751665 elements. which shoud work as the length of my df is 751665, i need to look deeper to see what is wrong.

Comment: And yes, transform is much more appropriate than apply function, thanks for your reply and i will look through my code and see what is going wrong.

Comment: i tried testing code using transform function, it works well with mathematical operations such as sum, mean ,etc. But it does not work well with dropna(). i think dropna() function      somehow mess up the size of data and it gives error message of "length mismatch".

Comment: And thanks for your solution, it is good to know i can use transform function on other operations.

Comment: i have create a dataframe which has only 6 rows as above and it works. Just that it does not work on my own dataframe. I think it maybe because there are rows in some labels only contains nan which cannot undergoes transform function. what do i do in such case? i will give an upvote to your solution as it works as asked in the question.

Comment: I have confirmed the length mismatch error is due to Only nan value in some labels. I create the above dataframe and add 2 more rows with label 'C' with all nan and using the transform function and it gives the length mismatch error.

Comment: Thanks for debugging the cause of error. Can you please check: `df.groupby('label').transform(lambda s: w.shift() if not (w := s.dropna()).empty else None)`. Basically we are returning a scalar value `None` when all the values in the label is null.

Comment: it still gives length mismatch error. I am trying to fill cells with all nan value within a group some sort of dummy value and then transform it.  And afterwards to see if i can fill those cells back with nan.

Comment: i will post it here if i find a neat way to do it. And thanks again for your solution, it gives me clear direction what to do and it helps me a lot.

Comment: Well, again there are more than Only nan value within a group that was causing the length mismatch error. And i am not able to figure out what it is, at least not within a short period of time as the data size is too large. But there is one thing i can confirm, 
Shubham Sharma's solution do solve the length mismatch error cause by Only nan value within a group. I create dataframe with some groups that contains Only nan value, and Shubham Sharma's solution works like a charm. I guess i have to work more closely to see what is wrong with my dataset.

Comment: @beginer101 Once again thanks for your debugging efforts. If you don't mind sharing the dataset I can actually take a look at the problem. You can send it to me over email.

Comment: hi Shubham, it is a dataset of stock historical daily data i download using yfinance, i combine the dividend paid with datetime and that's why there are tons of nan value since dividend dont get paid out evey day. And i find out an interesting fact why else would give length mismatch error, which if there is single non nan row and nan row with a group, df.groupby('label').transform(lambda s: w.shift() if not (w := s.dropna()).empty else None) will give length mismatch error.

Comment: Not sure if there are other cause that will give length mismatch error, but this type of error is mainly due to the dropna() which in some cells within a group it returns a series to be transform and some cells None, and it stops the transform which gives length mismatch error. i will demonstrate in a simple way in below that i find it funny and yet a headache.

Comment: so using df.groupby('label').transform(lambda s: w.shift() if not (w := s.dropna()).empty else None) on dataframe df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['a','a','b','b'], 'A1': [1,nan,nan,nan], 'A2':[1,nan,nan,nan]}) would give length mismatch error BUT df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['a','a','b','b'], 'A1': [1,nan,nan,nan], 'A2':[nan,2,nan,nan]}) would not. And using it on df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['a','a','b','b'], 'A1': [1,nan,nan,nan], 'A2':[nan,2,3,nan]}) would return series to cells what should originally transformed to the corresponding index.

Comment: i downloaded my dataset using yfinance through anaconda, which is a free package. It can be downloaded by typing (conda install -c conda-forge yfinance) through anaconda. And i capture the sp500 tickers from Internet and turn it to a list and feed it through yfinance using code (df = yf.download(tickers, period = 'Max', interval='1d', auto_adjust = True). The divdends data can be obtained by using df2 = yf.Ticker("ticker name to be filled").dividends which i need to loop through tickers list.

Comment: hi Shubham, i have found the solution to the question. Simply changing the code to df[columns] = df.dropna(subset = columns, how = 'all').groupby('label').transform(lambda x: x.dropna().shift(1))[columns] would do. And thanks again for mentioning the transform function, i would not be able to solve the problem myself without your help!